# Checking if input is duplicate from the values in ul

Tags: javascript, list, cordova, for-loop

My list looks like this

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>
```

I want to check if the plain text I scanned from my QR Code is not a duplicate values of the items in the list.

```
var ul = document.getElementById("myList");
var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
var check;
var myText = result.text;
var myTextTwo =  myText.replace(/['"]+/g, '');

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

  if (myTextTwo != items[i].innerHTML) {
    check = true
  }
  else if (myTextTwo == items[i].innerHTML) {
    check = false;                   
    break;
  }
}

if (check = true) {
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(myTextTwo);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);

} else if (check = false){
  alert("You have scanned this item before.");
}
```

For instance, everytime i run the above code and my QR code contain plain text of "Coffee", it does show the alert of "You have scanned this item before." However, it still append the plain text onto list. May I know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorrect way of comparing.

You are doing `if (check = true)` which is incorrect (you are assigning check as true inside the if block) should have been as below:

```
 if (check == true) {
                   var node = document.createElement("li");
                   var textnode = document.createTextNode(myTextTwo);
                   node.appendChild(textnode);
                   document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);

               }
               else if (check == false){
                   alert("You have scanned this item before.");
               }
```

or

```
 if (check) {
                   var node = document.createElement("li");
                   var textnode = document.createTextNode(myTextTwo);
                   node.appendChild(textnode);
                   document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);

               }
               else {
                   alert("You have scanned this item before.");
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `==` instead of `=`

```
if (check == true) {
  var node = document.createElement("li");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(myTextTwo);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);

} else if (check == false){
  alert("You have scanned this item before.");
}
```

or you can do this too:

```
if(check){
...
}else{
...
}
```